# What is the VBA equivalent of COLUMN() ie find the column of the cell that the formula is in, without a reference being provided?

Tags: excel, vba

It would look something like this

```
Function COL()

   COL = WorksheetFunction.Column()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Application.Caller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx) will give you a reference to the cell, from which you can get the column.  E.g.

```
Public Function COL()
    Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
    Case "Range"
       COL = Application.Caller.Column
    Case Else
       COL = "unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Brilliant. I did try to use Application.Caller but could not get it to work.   Unfortunately I'm not high enough ranked to upvote but many thanks.